# Regresar solo un campo de una lista en WCF

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

El método esta así:

```
public List<CivarTransporteService.Model.Cliente> getClientes()
{
   using (CivarTransporteService.Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer context = 
               new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
   {
            return context.Cliente.ToList();                
   }
}
```

el cs así:

```
public interface ICatalogsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<CivarTransporteService.Model.Cliente> getClientes();
}
```

obviamente me regresa todos los datos que hay en la tabla, pero solo necesito el campo de nombre, como puedo hacerle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te ofrezco 2 variantes:

### 1- Para el nombre de un solo cliente:

*(ojo! necesitas un identificador de cliente)*

Utilizando Linq filtras el cliente por su identificador y retornas el nombre, luego haces que la operación retorne una cadena: (este método retorna null si no existe el cliente)

```
public String getNombreCliente(int idCliente) {
    using (CivarTransporteService.Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer context = 
           new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
    {
        return (from c in context.Cliente
                where c.id == idCliente 
                select c.nombre).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

### 2- Para la lista de nombres:

```
public List<String> getNombreClientes(int idCliente) {
    using (CivarTransporteService.Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer context = 
           new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
    {        
        return (from c in context.Cliente
                select c.nombre).ToList();
    }
}
```

### Explicación:

Fíjate que en ambos casos el truco esta en el `select`, al pedir `c.nombre` (que asumo es un `String`) hace que el comando Linq retorne un `IEnumerable<String>` en lugar de `IEnumerable<CivarTransporteService.Model.Cliente>`

Luego con `ToList()` lo convertimos en una lista tipo `List<String>` justo lo que queremos retornar.

Por cierto, en el primer ejemplo utilizando `FirstOrDefault` le indico al `IEnumerable<String>` que retorne el primer registro o null si no hay resultados.

Las operaciones del servicio WCF, deben retornar el mismo tipo que las funciones de consulta.

```
public interface ICatalogsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    String getNombreCliente(int idCliente);

    [OperationContract]
    List<String> getNombreClientes();
}
```

Aquí te dejo un link con mas información sobre linq: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-AR/library/bb397926.aspx

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirve la lista de clientes.

Answer (score 2):

Agrego una variante a la respuesta de @mmeverdies pero con *lambda expression*:

```
public String getNombreCliente(int idCliente) {
    using (CivarTransporteService.Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer context = 
           new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
    {
        return context.Cliente.Where(c => c.id == idCliente)
                      .Select(c => c.nombre)
                      .FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

Ejemplos linq (en inglés):

[101 LINQ Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

[Linq Lambda expression samples](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/babu_2082/linq-operators-and-lambda-expression-syntax-examples/)

Comment: no sabia que convenia poner... :)

Comment: Es mas fácil de leer en la notación que utilizas vos! va a mi me parece mas natural. pero le agrego para que sepa que se puede hacer de dos maneras.